# can we set up mvc project as a virtual directory instead of an applicaiton

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to set up an mvc project as a virtual directory in IIS under an application rather than hosting it as an applicaiton by itself? basically I want to host multiple mvc projects as virtual directories inside an application. Please dont ask me why I have to do it in that way. I just have to do it . I tried it, but i just see the contents of the mvc folder being displayed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try asking on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Is MVC installed on the server? If not, did you add the MVC deployable dependencies to application?

Comment: Yes. MVC is installed on the server. I can run the project as a separate web application ( which is not exactly what I intend to do). I am just not able to get it to work as a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a Site. Now in IIS7, right click on the site and add application, this creates a virtual directory in the site that will behave as an application.

The Virtual Directory application will answer on whatever the site is bound too and the path.

IE. Site called mySite bound to mydomain.com, the directory the site is pointed to contains a folder called images.

We add the application with the alias MySubApp

you can then call your new application with http://mydomain.com/MySubApp

however, http://mydomain.com/images will go to the sites subfolder.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You. However my question was more specific to host a mvc project as a virtual directory in a application. The reason I am trying to do this is so that I have a way to share common library files across multiple mvc projects hosted as virtual directories inside a common application. COnfiguring each project as a separate application does not allow me to do that.  Your comment mainly explains how to create a virtual directory in a application and what it can be used for.

Comment: @MohanB sorry misunderstood your question. Can you register your dlls in the GAC? (although i personally wouldn't)

Comment: if sharing dlls is the concern see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691225/is-there-any-way-to-have-multiple-iis-virtual-directories-applications-share-a

Comment: Keeping Sharing dll's out of the context of this issue, I am trying to rule out the fact that A MVC project cannot be made to set up as a virtual directory and has to be set up only as a web application. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to run an MVC project as a virtual directory that is not set to be an application. This is because it uses many iis hooks like HttpHandlers among other things.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was guessing. Just wanted to make sure before tossing that option out completely.